# Cannot view the Spark UI using cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, spark-ui

I want to enable the spark ui for my glue jobs. I followed [Enabling the Spark UI for Jobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-ui-jobs.html) and [Launching the Spark History Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-ui-history.html), which I used default yml file provided by this guide to launch stack on cloudformation. After the stack was CREATE_COMPLETE, I got the SparkUiPublicUrl from the Outputs of the stack, but I couldn't open this url, which means I couldn't view the spark ui. The thing I have tried was to modify the inbound rules of security group, which is as following, but still not working. Have I missed something here?

[inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJldh.png)

Comment: did you find the solution. I am also facing the same issue?